# How much resources are good enough for 3.9.2

Tags: multisite, server, hosting, server-load

I have the following specification:

- memory_limit(maximal 128 MB),
- max_execution_time(max 60 sec)
- same PHP-Prozesse(max 10)

Is this good enough for wordpress? I am having a small site with around 100 visits a day, so nothing really large. Do you think I could host 2 other wordpress installations on the server?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: You should be fine..

Comment: @Sisir Thx for your answer! How many resources do I need for one install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be enough if you don’t install poorly written plugins or themes.

You should use PHP 5.5 and its built-in [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) and a multisite setup for more sites. This will reduce load time and the resources you need for the sites.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I have read through OPcache. What do you exactly mean by that? How to use it?

Comment: @Kare It is enabled by default, but you should check that. OPcache eliminates the need to recompile the PHP scripts for every request. `wpkrauts.com` for example is a multisite with OPcache (and no caching plugin). Average page generation time: 0.1 seconds.

Comment: Thx for your reply! Which multisite plugin do you recommend?

Comment: @Kare You don’t need any special plugin to run a multisite. See my [installation guide](http://make.marketpress.com/multilingualpress/2014/02/how-to-install-multi-site/).